# Solving an equation with an integral

Tags: integral-equations

I need to solve the following equation for $v(x)$:
$$\int_0^tv(x)(x+1)dx=f(t)$$
I am given the function $f(t)$. I've done this so far:

If we derive both sides by $t$, we get $v(t)(t+1)=f'(t)$ and $\bar{v}(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{t+1}$. The problem is that I am still off by a constant, i.e., the above only guarantees that : $\int_0^t\bar{v}(x)(x+1)dx+c=f(t)$ which is not enough for me.

Comment: **Hint:** consider taking the Fourier or Laplace transform from both sides, solve algebraic equation and making the inverse transform.

Comment: @monhawk: how should that help?

Comment: If your $f(0)=0$, then $c\equiv0$ for any $\nu(x)$. Isn't it?

Comment: @0x2207: yes, the constant is in fact $f(0)$.

Comment: @Fabian, from definition $\int_{0}^{0} g(x) dx \equiv 0$

Comment: @Fabian: The transform would "eat" the integral and we'll have the multiply of two images: $\mathcal{F}[v(x)]\cdot \mathcal{F}[x+1]$. And $\mathcal{F}[f(t)]$.

Comment: @0x2207: he has $f(t)$ given and searches for $v(x)$. The correct statement is, that the equation does not have a solution unless $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @m0nhawk: I do not understand how the transform would eat the integral. Could you expand your comment a bit?

Comment: @Fabian: This is the [Fredholm equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FredholmIntegralEquationoftheFirstKind.html) and the integral represent the convolution with the kernel (kernel and function can be choosed arbitrary in this particular case - no $t$ in under-integral functions). And for every (I don't know a contradiction example) integral transform the convolution of two function transforms into the multiplication of the transforms. See [convolution theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvolutionTheorem.html) for details. And the constant would naturally appear after transforms.

Comment: @monhawk: [Here](http://planetmath.org/LaplaceTransformOfConvolution.html) is the convolutions theorem for the Laplace transform. I am just not sure how you imagine to choose $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that the integral in the post corresponds to a convolutions for which one can apply this theorem.

Comment: @Fabian: I'm also meet so troubles when I start to apply my hint - looks like it was to good to be true.

Comment: Thanks for this info. The problem does look like Fredholm equation described. My only problem is that $f(0)\neq 0$, does this mean that there is no $v\in L_2[0,1]$ that satisfy the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that the constant $c$ in your post is in fact $f(0)$. Furthermore, a little thought shows that your equations cannot be solved unless $f(0)=0$ (just plug in $t=0$ in your equation and you find $0=f(0)$).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what is the problem here. Obsviously $f(0)=0$ (for the equation to have a solution) and by deriving as you said, we get
$$v(t)=\frac{f^{\prime}(t)}{t+1}$$
If we substitue this back in the orginal equation we have
$$f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f^{\prime}(x)dx=f(t)-f(0)=f(t)$$
which is true

Comment: The problem is the given $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: Then the problem has no solutions